# ElectricPutty - Thumber add-on not working with EE 2.9.2

Tags: 2.9

upgraded from 2.8.1 to 2.9.2 and ElectricPutty's add-on Thumber stopped working.  Any ideas?

Getting this debugging output:

(1.414562 / 37.32MB) Calling Class/Method: Thumber/create
(1.414701 / 37.32MB) -> Class Called: Thumber
(1.414785 / 37.33MB) -> Method Called: create
(1.575988 / 37.33MB) **Thumber** Can't find Ghostscript on your server.
(1.576109 / 37.33MB) -> Data Returned

Ghostscript has been installed for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens using Thumber 1.2. Rolling back to Thumber 1.1 returns normal functionality.